# jQuery - select the associated label element of a input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a set of input fields, some of them have labels associated, some not:

```
<label for="bla">bla</label> <input type="text" id="bla" />

<label for="foo">bla <input type="checkbox" id="foo" /> </label>

<input ... />
```

so, how can I select the associated label for each input, if it exists?

Comment: Will they always have the `for` attribute set?

Comment: no, because some of the fiels don't have labels...

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186416/jquery-selector-for-the-label-of-a-checkbox :)

Comment: What I meant was if there's an input that has a label, will the label  always have the `for` attribute set. Naturally if there's no label, there's no `for` attribute. :o)

Answer (score 226, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on the order of elements by using `prev` or `next`. Just use the `for` attribute of the label, as it should correspond to the ID of the element you're currently manipulating:

```
var label = $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']");
```

However, there are some cases where the label will not have `for` set, in which case the label will be the parent of its associated control. To find it in both cases, you can use a variation of the following:

```
var label = $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]');

if(label.length <= 0) {
    var parentElem = $(this).parent(),
        parentTagName = parentElem.get(0).tagName.toLowerCase();
    
    if(parentTagName == "label") {
        label = parentElem;
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for clumsy way to search for parent label tag. Also, <label> could be not an immediate parent of element. See my solution.

Answer (score 59):

There are two ways to specify label for element:

1. Setting label's "for" attribute to element's id
2. Placing element inside label

So, the proper way to find element's label is

```
   var $element = $( ... )

   var $label = $("label[for='"+$element.attr('id')+"']")
   if ($label.length == 0) {
     $label = $element.closest('label')
   }

   if ($label.length == 0) {
     // label wasn't found
   } else {
     // label was found
   }
```

Answer (score 15):

As long and your `input` and `label` elements are associated by their `id` and `for` attributes, you should be able to do something like this:

```
$('.input').each(function() { 
   $this = $(this);
   $label = $('label[for="'+ $this.attr('id') +'"]');
   if ($label.length > 0 ) {
       //this input has a label associated with it, lets do something!
   }
});
```

If `for` is not set then the elements have no semantic relation to each other anyway, and there is no benefit to using the label tag in that instance, so hopefully you will always have that relationship defined.

Comment: In addition to the "for" attribute, the semantic relationship can be established by the input element being *within* the label -- see the answer by Maxim Kulkin

Comment: You mixed up the defining and using variables in php and javascript