# Trying to have a link + checkbox, both clickable and text change on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Currently I'm just using jQuery to have a checkbox and a text, with the text to change after the checkbox is ticked, but I'm trying to work it so that the box OR text can be clicked and the result is changed text and checked box?

Can anybody assist me further?

[image]

Comment: Please post the code you're already tried.

Comment: what hv you tried so far?

Answer (score 5):

just put a label text around the checkbox and text, so it becomes something  like:

```
    <label><input type="checkbox" />Add to cart</label>
```

This makes the text part of the checkbox

Answer (score 2):

see [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/TZC9f/1/)

**in html**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test"> <label for="test">text</label>
```

**in JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#test").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).next("label").text("Added");
    } else {
      $(this).next("label").text("Add to Cart"); // your default color set
    }
  });
});
```

reference  **[checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)**

jQuery.**[next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)**

Comment: Unless you need to, you shouldn't rely on the order of elements by using `prev` or `next`.  See [Select the associated label element of a input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844594/jquery-select-the-associated-label-element-of-a-input-field).  Also, doesn't address OP's question of how to change the label **text**

Answer (score 0):

using label and setting the for attribute, you can click at the text, and the box will be checked/unchecked...

```
<label for="check1">Label for checkbox</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" value="value1">Option</input>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML

For the **HTML** part, there are [**two ways to specify a label for an element**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18432439/1366033):

1. Setting the label's [**`for`**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp) attribute to the element's id

   ```html
   <input type='checkbox' id='chkCart' />
   <label for='chkCart'>Add to Cart</label>
   ```
2. Placing the element inside a label

   ```html
   <label >
       <input type='checkbox' />
       Add to Cart
   </label>
   ```

I'll use the first one

#### JavaScript

Then you can use **jQuery** to handle the rest:

- First, make sure the DOM is loaded by wrapping your javascript in a [**`.ready`**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function (since we'll be looking to modify these elements).
- Then attach an event handler to the checkbox click event by using the [**`.click`**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function.
- Since we've set the `for` attribute for this particular label, we can use the [**`attribute`**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) equals selector (`[name="value"]`) by looking for a label with the same `for` value as our calling element's `id`.
- You can check if the object that raised the event is checked on or off by using the [**`:checked`**](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector.
- You can use the Javascript's [**`ternary`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx) operator to conditionally set each value
- Then rename the label using the [**`.text`**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function

It should all look like this:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#chkCart").click(function () {
        var lbl = $(`label[for='${this.id}']`);
        var msg = this.checked ? "Added" : "Add to Cart"
        lbl.text(msg);
    });
});
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets & [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/4cWgN/)

```js
$(function () {
    $("#chkCart").click(function () {
        var lbl = $(`label[for='${this.id}']`);
        var msg = this.checked ? "Added" : "Add to Cart"
        lbl.text(msg);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='checkbox' id='chkCart'/>
<label for='chkCart'>Add to Cart</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/KBFk4/)

Try this

```
$("#chk").click(function () {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).next().fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $("#chk").next().text("Added");
        }).fadeIn("slow");

    } else {

        $(this).next().fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $("#chk").next().text("Add to cart");
        }).fadeIn("slow");
    }

});
```

### html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk">
<label for="chk" style="text-decoration:underline">Add to cart</label>
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can associate onChange event to your checkbox , if it's checked , you show your text,else you show the link . **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/udfgG/)**

**HTML code:**

```
<input type='checkbox' id='check'/>
<label><a href='#'>add to cart</a></label>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery Code :**

```
$('#check').change(function(){

  if ($(this).is(":checked")) $(this).next().text('added');
  else $(this).next().html("<a href='#'>add to cart</a>");

});
```