# Get label of element in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to get label of element as string and alert that string in jquery. I wrote code below but i get [object][Object] value. I tried html() and text() too but it didnt work.

```
 function seatObject(id, label, status, token){
        this.id = id;
        this.label = label; 
        this.status = status;
        this.token = token;
    }

    for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {            
      var temp = new seatObject("#" + x, "label" + x, "available", "");
      seats[x] = temp;                        
      $("#" + x).click(function () {
        currentSeat = $(this).attr("id");
        var label = $("label[for="+$(this).attr('id')+"]");
        alert(label);   
      });
    }
```

Also this is my tag;

```
<rect style="fill: #888888;" id="0" width="35.823246" height="35.823246" x="299.87155" y="65.999405" class="seatObj" label="A24"></rect>
```

Comment: var label = $("label");
alert(label.text()); This works for me http://fiddle.jshell.net/kU7Pb/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844594/jquery-select-the-associated-label-element-of-a-input-field

Comment: I tried it but i got [object][Object] value

Comment: what does your `seatObject` function do ? can you post the code ?

Comment: function seatObject(id, label, status, token){
             this.id = id;
             this.label = label;
             this.status = status;
             this.token = token;
        }

Comment: Where do you actually add the label node to your DOM document ?

Comment: var temp = new seatObject("#" + x, "label" + x, "available", ""); In this line I add the label node. When i write these codes;  currentSeat = $(this).attr("id"); I am getting id. After that, I want to show user that you clicked that seat with label of seat

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp label use this

```
var labelText  = $('#<%= label.ClientID %>').val();
```

Or If you are using html label use this

```
var labelText = $('#label').val();
```

This should work for u..

Answer (score 0):

Give class to your label since you are using server-side objects.

```
<label runat="server" id="myLabel" CssClass="myLabelClass"></label>

alert($(".myLabelClass").text());
```

should work.