# Getting the text of a label without a child input

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given a this HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input id="data_point_occupation" value="occupation" type="checkbox">
    Occupation
  </label>
</div>
```

I want to get the text content of the label ("Occupation"), but not anything else. Since I'm already using jQuery on the page, I decided to try getting it with jQuery. So I tried the below:

```
var label = $("#data_point_occupation").parent("label").contents().get(0).nodeValue
console.log(label) // outputs what looks like just white space
console.log(label.length) // outputs 25
```

I tried a few other variations in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags), but all of them had similar results.

How can I get the text of this label?

**Related but didn't answer my question:**
[jQuery - select the associated label element of a input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844594/jquery-select-the-associated-label-element-of-a-input-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you are looking for:

```js
var label = $("#data_point_occupation").parent("label");
console.log(label.text().trim())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input id="data_point_occupation" value="occupation" type="checkbox">
    Occupation
  </label>
</div>
```

This will get the text of the element and trim any whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .text() property
Here is code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($("label").text());
});
```

Example on http://jsbin.com/dukokucuku/edit?html,js,output