# How to get label value from input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have matching `input` and `label` elements:

```js
console.log('LABEL:', $('label[for="8"]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ad_numbers">
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="6" />6<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="7" />7<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="8" checked/>8<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="9" />9<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="10" />10<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="11" />11<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="12" />12<br>
</div>

<div class="ad_numbers ad_prices">
  <label for="6" id="6">$50</label>
  <label for="7" id="7">$45</label>
  <label for="8" id="8">$40</label>
  <label for="9" id="9">$35</label>
  <label for="10" id="10">$30</label>
  <label for="11" id="11">$25</label>
  <label for="12" id="12">$20</label>
</div>
```

Say input `8` is checked, what would the jquery selector look like to target the accompanying `label` element?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844594/jquery-select-the-associated-label-element-of-a-input-field

Comment: Your inputs and labels are not matching as of now. Use `<label for="foo">` for `<input id="foo" />`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You got it backwards a label for attribute value should be the ID of an input. So move the id to the inputs.

Comment: Please provide the jQuery that you have tried but failed to get desired results.

Comment: The following selector does not work: `console.log('LABEL:', $('label[for="6"]'));` after using @connexo's code

Comment: Added Javascript example code that on `change` console.logs the corresponding label.

Comment: Added the `console.log` statement from your comment to your code showing that **it works as expected**.

Answer (score 1):

You don't connect `input` and `label` based on `value`, but using `for` on the label matching `id` on the input:

```js
const ad_pos_radios = document.querySelectorAll('[name=ad_pos]')
const ad_pos_labels = document.querySelectorAll('ad_numbers.ad_prices label')

for (const ad of Array.from(ad_pos_radios)) {
  ad.addEventListener('change', () => {
    console.log(document.querySelector(':checked').labels[0].textContent);
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="ad_numbers">
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" id="6" value="6" />6<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" id="7" value="7" />7<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" id="8" value="8" checked/>8<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" id="9" value="9" />9<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" id="10" value="10" />10<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" id="11" value="11" />11<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" id="12" value="12" />12<br>
</div>

<div class="ad_numbers ad_prices">
  <label for="6">$50</label>
  <label for="7">$45</label>
  <label for="8">$40</label>
  <label for="9">$35</label>
  <label for="10">$30</label>
  <label for="11">$25</label>
  <label for="12">$20</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Right. Do you know what the jquery selector would be for targeting those labels?

Comment: It is unclear what your are actually trying to achieve. Please describe that.

Comment: Thanks - Are you able to use jQuery code instead of javascript?

Comment: Why would you want that? jQuery is not helpful here. The earlier you start learning to do things without jQuery, the better.

Comment: Using it as an array and loop through it is not necessary, as long as you get right result for selected radio box.

Comment: @AslanShemilov Why not simply learn some basic Javascript instead of posting misleading and wrong comments? You are looping throught the exact same array, only you are doing it using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not modify the HTML code properly, as mentioned by @connexo.

You can use this selector:

```
".ad_numbers input[type=radio][checked]"
```

Something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var checked = $(".ad_numbers input[type=radio][checked]")[0];
  console.log($("#" + checked.value).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
down vote favorite I have matching input and label elements:

<div class="ad_numbers">
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="6" />6<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="7" />7<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="8" checked/>8<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="9" />9<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="10" />10<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="11" />11<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="12" />12<br>
</div>

<div class="ad_numbers ad_prices">
  <label for="6" id="6">$50</label>
  <label for="7" id="7">$45</label>
  <label for="8" id="8">$40</label>
  <label for="9" id="9">$35</label>
  <label for="10" id="10">$30</label>
  <label for="11" id="11">$25</label>
  <label for="12" id="12">$20</label>
</div>
```

Update:

Based on @connexo suggestion.

The proper selector is:

```
".ad_numbers input[type=radio]:checked"
```

```js
$(function() {
  var checked = $(".ad_numbers input[type=radio]:checked")[0];
  console.log($("#" + checked.value).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
down vote favorite I have matching input and label elements:

<div class="ad_numbers">
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="6" />6<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="7" />7<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="8" checked/>8<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="9" />9<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="10" />10<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="11" />11<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="12" />12<br>
</div>

<div class="ad_numbers ad_prices">
  <label for="6" id="6">$50</label>
  <label for="7" id="7">$45</label>
  <label for="8" id="8">$40</label>
  <label for="9" id="9">$35</label>
  <label for="10" id="10">$30</label>
  <label for="11" id="11">$25</label>
  <label for="12" id="12">$20</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Your selector `input[type=radio][checked]` will always return the element with the ***attribute*** `checked` - which will never change, no matter which radio button is currently selected. If you want the *currently* checked element, use `:checked` pseudo selector instead.

Comment: Thanks @connexo for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function() {
    $("input[type=radio][name=ad_pos]").on("change", function() {
      var selected = $("input[type=radio][name=ad_pos]:checked").val();
      console.log(selected);
      if (selected) {
        var label = $('.ad_numbers.ad_prices label[for="' + selected + '"]').text();
        console.log(label);
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<div class="ad_numbers">
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="6" checked />6<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="7" />7<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="8" />8<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="9" />9<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="10" />10<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="11" />11<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ad_pos" value="12" />12<br>
</div>

<div class="ad_numbers ad_prices">
  <label for="6" id="6">$50</label>
  <label for="7" id="7">$45</label>
  <label for="8" id="8">$40</label>
  <label for="9" id="9">$35</label>
  <label for="10" id="10">$30</label>
  <label for="11" id="11">$25</label>
  <label for="12" id="12">$20</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the DOM api for HTMLInputElements. They have a property called `labels` which holds an array of all attached label elements. Furthermore you solution does not link the `label`s to the `input`s.

Comment: If you prefer use array for all attached labels, doesn't mean that everyone has to follow your preference. I gave clear answer to the question.

Comment: This site is to give a hand with solution for problems in code, not to show/hide your competence and not to show the ability of show off.

Comment: I'm not shwoing off, I'm correcting your misleading and low quality/wrong comments. I hope you are willing to learn instead of continuing to insist on your lack of knowledge.

Comment: I didn't say you're. Sorry and thank you for corrections.