# How to get value of the span corresponding to the checked checkbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I need to retrieve the span value as per checkbox checked using Jquery. I am explaining my code below.

```html
<div class="col-md-3 tourpricecolumn">
  <h6>Select Vehicle</h6>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="sVehicle">
    <span class="checkround"></span>Car &nbsp;
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">435</span>
  </label>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="sVehicle">
    <span class="checkround"></span>Bus &nbsp;
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">356</span>
  </label>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="sVehicle">
    <span class="checkround"></span>Tempo Traveller &nbsp;
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">567</span>
  </label>
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="vehicleprice" />
</div>
```

Here my requirement is when checkbox will be checked then its corresponding span value will be etched and add to that `hidden input textbox`.

Comment: I see multiple `<span>` elements, can you clarify exactly which one you're looking to get the `.text()` from.

Comment: @Twisty : I need value from this `<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">435</span>` span element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - select the associated label element of a input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844594/jquery-select-the-associated-label-element-of-a-input-field)

Comment: Duplicate because your label is wrapped around the requested span.

Comment: Why not just use a `value` attribute on the `input`? Forget about the hidden input and JS shenanigans entirely.

Comment: That or properly set a specific class for that span, so no risk of confusion if someone is placing the span at a wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `change` event your `radio` buttons and then get your span text in that. Add `vehicleprice` id to your hidden field

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type='radio']").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                var spanValue = $(this).parent().find("span:last").text().trim();
               // var oldVal = $("#vehicleprice").val();
                $("#vehicleprice").val(spanValue);
                
                console.log(spanValue);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 tourpricecolumn">
     <h6>Select Vehicle</h6>
     <label class="radio">
     <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="sVehicle">
     <span class="checkround"></span>Car &nbsp;<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">435</span>
   </label>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <label class="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="sVehicle">
   <span class="checkround"></span>Bus &nbsp;<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">356</span>
 </label>
<div class="clear"></div>
 <label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="sVehicle">
<span class="checkround"></span>Tempo Traveller &nbsp;<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">567</span>
 </label>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="vehicleprice" id="vehicleprice" />
 </div>
```

Comment: is there any issue with that? Its pretty much clear what he is asking for

Comment: It is clear. He wants the value inside the `span` having the price.

Comment: I added a console.log in your function

Comment: you were missing id for hidden field, that's why it was returning `undefined`

Comment: He wants only the price

Answer (score 1):

You should use `change` event listener for `input[name='sVehicle']` elements and in function use `.nextAll()` to selecting next element after target input.

```js
$(":radio").change(function(){
  $("input[name='vehicleprice']").val(
    $("input[name='sVehicle']:checked").nextAll(".badge").text()
  );
  console.log($("input[name='vehicleprice']").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 tourpricecolumn">
  <h6>Select Vehicle</h6>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="sVehicle">
    <span class="checkround"></span>Car &nbsp;
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">435</span>
  </label>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="sVehicle">
    <span class="checkround"></span>Bus &nbsp;
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">356</span>
  </label>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="sVehicle">
    <span class="checkround"></span>Tempo Traveller &nbsp;
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">567</span>
  </label>
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="vehicleprice" />
</div>
```

Note that you can use `.trigger("change")` to fire change event on page load to set value of first checked radio into hidden input.

```
$(":radio").change(function(){
  $("input[name='vehicleprice']").val(
    $("input[name='sVehicle']:checked").nextAll(".badge").text()
  );
}).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is small jquery code for getting corresponding span value :

```js
$(document).on('change','input[name="sVehicle"]',function(){
  
  var spanval =$(this).closest('label.radio').find('span.badge').text();
  $("input[name='vehicleprice']").val(spanval);
  console.log($("input[name='vehicleprice']").val());
});
```