# how to check element have class or not ? already use (hasClass method)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML or mark up .

```
<fieldset class="ui-dform-fieldset">
    <input type="text" id="totalRetryCount" name="totalRetryCount" tabindex="1" onblur="validateElement('Configuration', 'testSuiteConfigurationform','totalRetryCount')" class="ui-dform-text">
    <legend class="ui-dform-legend">Total Retry Count</legend>
    <label for="totalRetryCount" class="error">Please enter a valid number.</label>
</fieldset>
```

I want to check whether label have error class or not.I did like that

when I debug my element value is "totalRetryCount" .But it is not showing alert.

```
element ="totalRetryCount"

if($("#"+element+" "+"label").hasClass('error')){
        alert('-sdafs-')
    }
```

Comment: Try debugging your code a little bit better. A possible error is not finding the element, log that to the console to see if you actually get it properly.

Comment: `$("label[for='" + totalRetryCount + "']").hasClass(...`

Comment: As an aside, `("#"+element + " label")` would do it, no need to concatenate two static strings....

Answer (score 5):

Your selector is wrong. The `totalRetryCount` ID is on an `input`, which can have no children.

The targeted `label` is a sibling, so  use the *[next-siblings-selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)* instead:

```
if ($("#" + element + " ~ label").hasClass("error")) {
    alert("found error");
}
```

Or this:

```
if ($("#" + element + " ~ label.error").length) {
    alert("found error");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `input` tag is never closed, `input` is also self closing. Since you have an ID, just do:

```
$("#totalRetryCount").siblings("label").hasClass("error");
```

Answer (score 1):

The string `totalRetryCount` is a value of `for` attribute, not an `id` of parent element.

```
var element ="totalRetryCount"
if($("label[for='"+element+"']").hasClass('error')){
    alert('-sdafs-')
}

(or)

$("#" + element).siblings("label[for='"+element+"']").hasClass("error");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your id/class identifiers are off, you are checking for label as a child of an element with id `totalRetryCount`, but it is not a child of that element.

This works

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="ui-dform-fieldset">
    <input type="text" id="totalRetryCount" name="totalRetryCount" tabindex="1" onblur="validateElement('Configuration', 'testSuiteConfigurationform','totalRetryCount')" class="ui-dform-text">    
   <legend class="ui-dform-legend">Total Retry Count</legend>
   <label for="totalRetryCount" class="error">Please enter a valid number.</label>
</fieldset>
```

jQuery:

```
if($(".ui-dform-fieldset label").hasClass('error')){
        alert('-sdafs-')
    }
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tys57/)

Comment: Personally I'm fond of `$('#' + element + ' label.error').size()`. Fewer trips through the DOM and doesn't involve another check of a property.

Comment: @BradChristie this will not works, see answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24165166/133408

Comment: @PeterM: Just accidentally omitted `~` in comment. Should be `$('#' + element + ' ~label.error').size()` Could also be `$('label[for="' + element + '"].error').size()` to be more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is incorrect. See here for a question that explains the label selector. [jQuery selector for the label of a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186416/jquery-selector-for-the-label-of-a-checkbox)

It should look more like this.

```
if ( $("label[for='" + element + "']").hasClass( 'error' ) )
{
    alert( 'Heres my alert!' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#totalRetryCount").siblings('label').hasClass('error')){
    alert('-sdafs-'); }
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65C7F/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("label[for=totalRetryCount]").hasClass('error')){
   alert('-sdafs-')
}
```

Actually if you don't have non alphanumeric characters in your `id` then you don't need to surround with `' '` single quote.