# How to get the label for a checkbox with a specific value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the label for a checkbox using jQuery. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cb_type[]" value="sold" >Sold</label>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
$("label[for=:checkbox[value='sold']]");
```

I know that this works:

```
$(":checkbox[value='sold']");
```

Any ideas on how I can get this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically had it.  Just needed the parent.

```js
console.log($(":checkbox[value='sold']").parent());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cb_type[]" value="sold" >Sold</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, refer this post

[jQuery selector for the label of a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186416/jquery-selector-for-the-)
label-of-a-checkbox

you have to have a

your label tag doesnt have explicit for attribute but use the nested tags.