# Display an error message in HTML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to display an error message using jQuery.  It is not displaying when there is an error. I have taken this from another question and modified it.

The jQuery (contained in an if exception test which is triggered) is:

```
$("#projectIDSelect").html("Please select a Project ID").addClass("error-msg"); // chained methods
```

The html is:

```
<p>
    <label for="projectIDSelect">Project ID<span class="required">*</span></label>

    <!--Place to load the Project Names into for selection -->
    <select class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"  style="height:30px; color:black;" id="projectIDSelect" name="projectIDSelect" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Project</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Also, after this has run the dropdown no longer contains the options (these have been dynamically loaded).

Comment: I feel like your problem lies in calling a `.html(...)` method on your `<select>` element which parses your string input and replaces the `innerHTML`. Instead, use `.text(...)` method described [here](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2).

Comment: Also, there's no sense to populate `<select>` tag with weird content (i.e., not `<option>`s). Add a separate container, like other people suggested here, specifically for displaying your status updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#projectIDSelect` is a combo or drop down box. and in your jquery when you update content using `.html` it will not show error because its not possible to show html content in a drop down box.

You need to add separate identifier for showing message.

Your code could be:

```
<p>
    <label for="projectIDSelect">Project ID<span class="required">*</span></label>

    <!--Place to load the Project Names into for selection -->
    <select class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"  style="height:30px; color:black;" id="projectIDSelect" name="projectIDSelect" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Project</option>
    </select>
    <p id="projectIDSelectError"></p>
</p>
```

and your jquery could be:

```
$("#projectIDSelectError").html("Please select a Project ID").addClass("error-msg"); // chained methods
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
    if (!$('#projectIDSelect option:selected').val()) {
        $("#divError").html("Please select a Project ID").addClass("error-msg"); // chained methods
    } else {
        $("#divError").html("").removeClass("error-msg");
    }
    $("#projectIDSelect").change(function() {
        if (!$('option:selected').val()) {
            $("#divError").html("Please select a Project ID").addClass("error-msg"); // chained methods
        } else {
            $("#divError").html("").removeClass("error-msg");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.error-msg {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
   <label for="projectIDSelect">Project ID<span class="required">*</span></label>
   <!--Place to load the Project Names into for selection -->
   <select class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"  style="height:30px; color:black;" id="projectIDSelect" name="projectIDSelect" required>
      <option value=""  selected>Select a Project</option>
      <option value="1" >123</option>
      <option value="2" >321</option>
   </select>
</p>
<div id='divError'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting `id` in label  instead of  `for` selector ref [jQuery selector for the label of a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186416/jquery-selector-for-the-label-of-a-checkbox.Hope) this helps

```js
$("label[for='projectIDSelect']").html("Please select a Project ID").addClass("error-msg");
```

```css
.error-msg
{
color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <label for="projectIDSelect">Project ID<span class="required">*</span></label>

    <!--Place to load the Project Names into for selection -->
    <select class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"  style="height:30px; color:black;" id="projectIDSelect" name="projectIDSelect" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Project</option>
    </select>
</p>
```